# How can few .net projects use same dataset

Tags: asp.net, dataset, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new in asp.net.

The Case:

1. '.net console application' that runs once per day run code and insert data to MySql then put this data to DataSet.
2. I have 'ASP.NET MVC4 Website' that should access(only for read) the data that stored by 1 app in dataset.

What Should be the code and structure of this 2 app for make them work with same DataSet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate class library that contains your data access code, reference it from both the console app and the website app. Keep in mind your connection strings will have to be a part of the console app.config AND the website web.config.

Comment: Can you write some short code or reference to such article please

Comment: Instead of writing database code in your two applications, put it in a separate project. Add a reference to that project from the two other projects.

Comment: I can add reference from app 2 to app1 but what code should I write?(some example, i am new in .net - i am php/rails programmer that need to do staff in .net on the way)